# How to draw polygon as show in the image in google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have created an android app with a single screen and my activity/fragment has a google map as its main content.Now, how to show the shaded area on the map as shown in the **attached screen shot**. I have done lots of Research and Development on this topic but didn't get a perfect way to implement such a thing.

I am not asking to give me some sample code or post your code, just some proper direction & documentation.

[image: image description here]

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

To draw polygon use Polygon feature of Google map SDK. For more info refer [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/shapes#polygons). You need to provide the latitude longitude of path where you want to draw the polygon.